# How to keep uniqueness over a related list?

Tags: custom-object

I have a custom object (AKA License), that gets "rented/used" on a monthly basis.
There are 5 types/levels of rentals. I have created a custom object to represent a rental type, and each has it's own set of attrivutes.

My License can only have 1 rental level at a specific time (and its a monthly renewal process)

The rentals are saved as a related list of License. There is no active/disabled setting on a rental object, just start/end date. (so, if the date has passed on the latest rental for license - the license can't be used.

My question: How can I keep that only 1 rental period can be valid for a certain licenses?

If I add a simple Lookup from the License --> rental - isn't there a loop now?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I need to ensure a child record is unique across its parent's children:

1. Create a field on the child and make it unique
2. Use a work flow to update the field with the concatonation of the ParentID and the other values that make it unique - Set workflow to fire creation and every edit with criteria of created date != null.

This will ensure the record is unique for it parent and does not conflict with other records.

Comment: "parents children" means same as "...ensure a child record is unique across its siblings"?  Or across all children records of all parents ?

Comment: siblings........

Comment: that's what i thought you meant but missing apostrophe led to clarification question; tx for editing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Having a loop via two lookups isn't a bad thing, there's no reason why you can't use a Licence -> Rental lookup to maintain the 'current' licence, in fact it's quite a nice way of doing it as it absolutely ensures that there's only ever one current licence, your logic just needs to ensure it's the correct one.